# How to get the timer to return time java

Tags: java, swing, timer

Once I start running the timer, how do I get it to return how long has passed? Can this timer be set visible?

Comment: *"Can this timer be set visible?"*  ..How did you set it 'invisible' in the first place?  What does that mean?

Comment: I meant, a timer object is not like a jframe which i can see. The first answer below (second paragraph) answered this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that you pass as second argument to the Timer constructor implements ActionListener. Through that interface it receives a call to its actionPerformed method upon each alarm from the timer. The actionPerformed method has an ActionEvent parameter whose method getWhen gives the timestamp. You will need to store the original timestamp somewhere accessible if you want the ActionListener to compute the elapsed time.

A Swing Timer is a mechanism with no graphical representation of its own. If you like, your ActionListener can implement a graphical representation of the timer. It can be a graphic component such as a JPanel and its actionPerformed method can cause it to respond visibly, perhaps by drawing something, each time that the timer goes off.

Comment: If I say timer.start();, is there a timer behind the scene that is set off? Also, how would I call this 'timestamp' so that I can store it elsewhere?

Comment: What would be the ideal place to store these timestamps? There will be many so...all I can think of is something like a jtextarea.

Comment: You may only want to know the time since the previous actionPerformed. Normally that will be close to the amount of time that you requested anyway: see <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html> for details. If you want to know the actual elapsed time since the previous actionPerformed, your ActionListener object can simply have a single field where you store the timestamp from the previous actionPerformed.

Comment: And to get a timestamp before the first actionPerformed you can do `long timestamp = new java.util.Date().getTime()`.